# In Objective C, how to obtain the metaclass object?

Tags: objective-c, metaclass, objective-c-runtime

In `Objective-C`, how does one obtain the metaclass object? Both `[self class]` and `[ClassName class]` returns the Class object only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`objc_getMetaClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_getMetaClass)

**Edit:** Improved as per Greg's suggestion in the comments.

```
object_getClass([Class class]);
```

Comment: Don't do this. It breaks in some cases (such as two classes with the same name).

Comment: @qegal: Greg Parker is one of the developers of the Objective-C runtime. If he says it's risky, I would feel pretty hesitant about it.

Comment: @GregParker Thanks, improved the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
object_getClass([self class])
object_getClass([ClassName class])
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to use the objective-C runtime function `object_getClass` to get the class of the class object.

A good write up [What is a meta-class in Objective-C](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html) goes through some detail on meta-classes.  However, in some cases the class of the meta-class is the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do you wish to obtain information for the purposes of meta-programming / reflection?

This information is available via a [plain-C API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html).

Unlike some other object-oriented languages, the meta-class itself is pretty thin on information, with other C functions filling in the details.

If you're new to Objective-C, C and C++ it might be easier to use Mike Ash's [Objective-C wrapper library](https://github.com/mikeash/MAObjCRuntime).

Answer (score -2):

You can get the metaclass for an object via

```
[[self class] class]
```

The [self class] yields a pointer to the Class object (i.e. what the isa pointer points to).  Since this is an object with a class as well, you can follow the isa pointer again to get the metaclass.

You can find a diagram (http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/class%20diagram.pdf) in this blog post (http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html) an [another post](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html) that explain it differently.  Sorry for the weird links but I had to get past the reputation filter...

I would be curious to know why you would want a pointer to the metaclass though...

Comment: [[self class] class] returns the same instance as [self class]